# How to include and exclude ids in once query postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I use **PostgreSQL 13.3**

I'm trying to think how I can make include/exclude in query at the same time

I have **include_system_ids [1,5]** and **exclude_system_ids [3]**

There's one big table - records

system_records table

| record | system_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |

If a record contains an exclusive identifier, then it should not be included in the final selection. I had some several tries, but I didn't get a necessary result

**Awaiting result**: record with id 2

**Fact result**: 1, 2

My variants

```
select r.id from records r
left join (select record_id from system_records
   where system_id in (1,5)
) include_ids on r.id = include_ids
left join (select record_id from system_records
   where system_id not in (3)
) exclude_ids on r.id = exclude_ids.id
```

Honestly, I don't understand how I can do it((
Is there anyone who can help me

Comment: what is records table sample rows/records?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this query could be a solution ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sY4fwje8892XaxLwW4yrC4/0))

```
with x as (select record,string_agg(system_id::varchar,',') as sys_id from records group by record)
select records.* 
from records,x 
where records.record = x.record
and x.sys_id = '1,5'
```